# Prove that $ \frac{1}{x^5} $ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\frac{1}{x^5} $ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$. I tried by putting $\epsilon = 1$ but can't seem to find $x$ and $x'$ that would work.

Comment: $(0,2)$...................

Comment: A related exercise which might be interesting: prove that if $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ both exist.

Comment: This is a very good comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$$
and
$$y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

be two  sequences of reals in $(0,2)$.

it is clear that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(y_n-x_n)=0$$

but

$$f(y_n)-f(x_n)=(n+1)^5-n^5$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=+\infty (\ne 0)$$

We can conclude that $f$ is not uniformly continuous at $(0,2)$.

With $\epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon=1$ for example.
then for each $\eta>0$,

and very very large $n$, we have

$$|y_n-x_n|<\eta$$

because
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(y_n-x_n)=0$$
and
$$|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|>1$$
because
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=+\infty$$